# Copy Admin on All Emails To/From Specific Outside Email Address [Google Apps (GAM API)]

Tags: g-suite, gmail, forwarding, email

We use a fax-through-email service and I would like to keep track of our employees' usage of it. We use Google Apps for Business and I have installed/configured GAM API for the more advanced administration methods otherwise not supported by Google.

Using GAM (other suggestions welcome), is there a way to have all email correspondences to/from a specific outside email address be copied to admin email?

Google suggests I log into each and every user in my domain and set up their filters to allow this to happen, but doing so would take me over a month to finish.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Who's SMTP server are your users using?

Comment: Google's. smtp.gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Nearly all email agents keep logs indicating where an email originated and when it was going to.  Why not use that.

For security and privacy issues, there is no need to copy each email going to the FAX service.  In fact, I'd check your company's privacy procedures.

Comment: We want to verify that each page being sent/received (we pay per page sent/received) is being used for business-related purposes only. Our fax service faxes only the attachments, which obviously cannot be viewed from the log file.

If you seem to see no need to copy each email going to/from the FAX service, maybe you can suggest another way the admin can receive each incoming/outgoing fax?

We checked with legal. This is well within the confines of our company's privacy policy/procedures.